# How does my child component have access to `history` if it isn't passed as a propo?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a component called `Bar.js` that has a child component called `Search.js`. Inside `Bar.js` it is simply used like this: `<Search/>` so no props are passed in.

But `Search.js` looks like this so how is it using `history`?

```
const Search = () => {
  let term = "";

  return (
    <Route
      render={({ history }) => (
        <Form
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            history.push(`/search/${term}`);
          }}
          inline
        >
          <FormControl
            style={{ maxWidth: "150px", alignItems: "right" }}
            id="interval"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            className=" mr-sm-2"
            onChange={(e) => (term = e.target.value)}
            defaultValue={term}
          />
          <Button variant="light" style={{ marginRight: "0px" }} type="submit">
            {/* <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon={faSearch} /> */}
            <Image alt="search" src="/img/NavBar/search.svg" />
          </Button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default Search;
```

Comment: The render prop function has access to all the route props (match, location and history). Please read [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)

Comment: Whichever flavor of [`<Router/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) you are using sets the `history` in context. Then every [`Route`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) and [hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks) has access to that context

Comment: Ahh thank you @Brian just tested that out on another component where I was using `useHistory` and it worked.